# Need an INSERT ...SELECT statement, but I also want to manually set some fields

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert-select

I need an insert statement that will do roughly this:

```
INSERT INTO
    tblContent(postTitle, postBody, postAuthor, postDate, postApproved, fromSite)
     SELECT tblSubmissions.body
            WHERE tblSubmissions.submissionId = 1
```

But I need to manually supply the rest of the fields. Is this possible? Or do I need to insert once, and then update? If I need to insert, then update, I know that I can probably use PDO::lastInsertId for this, but could someone provide a clear example, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible : just inject the values you know into the `select` clause ;-)

For example, you could have something like this :

```
insert into your_table (field1, field2, field3)
select 'my_value', field_from_select, 152
from your_other_table
where ...
```

Here, `'my_value'` and `152` are values I know before -- and `field_from_select` is the dynamic field that comes from the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tblContent(postTitle, postBody, postAuthor, postDate, postApproved, fromSite)
SELECT 'title',tblSubmissions.body,'author',..... 
WHERE tblSubmissions.submissionId = 1
```